# “that of-” or ”one of-”

Tags: grammar

I often hear **(a)that of/those of**, but I don’t hear **(b) the one of**.

Is **(b)** common or strange among native speakers?

> (a) Computers at that time were quite different from **those of** today.
>
> (b) Computes at that time were quite different from the **ones of** today.

Comment: (b) is not _idiomatic_ (a natural thing for native speakers to say).

Comment: Aside from the typo of *computes* in the second sentence, I find nothing unusual about it.  In other words, it sounds idiomatic to me. It's something that people in Canada would say anyway. (I can't actually say which of the two sentences is more common; they seem about equal to me.)